# Simple injector 3.0 - generics registration

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I've upgraded to 3.0, and I'm having a little bit of trouble.  The following registration worked in 2.8, but is throwing an error in 3.0.  I'm thinking I'm not registering it correctly in 3.0, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

**2.8**

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof (IProducerQueue<,,>), typeof (ProducerQueue<,,>));
```

**3.0**

```
container.Register(typeof (IProducerQueue<,,>), typeof (ProducerQueue<,,>));
```

This worked in 2.8.  However, in 3.0 I am getting an error indicating that there are two possible registrations

**Error:**

> {"Multiple applicable registrations found for `IProducerQueue<FakeMessage, RedisQueueTransportConfigurationSend<RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>, RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>`. The applicable registrations are
>
> (1) the unconditional open generic registration for `IProducerQueue<TMessage, TTransport, TMessageData>` using `ProducerQueue<T, TTransport, TMessageData>` and
>
> (2) the unconditional closed generic registration for `IProducerQueue<FakeMessage, RedisQueueTransportConfigurationSend<RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>, RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>` using `IProducerQueue<FakeMessage, RedisQueueTransportConfigurationSend<RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>, RedisQueueAdditionalMessageData>`.
>
> If your goal is to make one registration a fallback in case another registration is not applicable, make the fallback registration last and check the Handled property in the predicate."}

I've tried calling the `RegisterConditional` method instead - that gives the same error, which makes sense, as the above is the only registration call for this type.

Comment: Can you update your code and show a complete reproducible example? I'm unable to reproduce your issue. What the exception message says is that you have a second registration somewhere: a closed one. Did you have an `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` registration in there that you changed to `Register(typeof(IProducerQueue<,,>), assemblies)`?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what's going on.  In this particular case, the registration for IProducerQueue is being overridden.  I'm pretty sure that i need to change how that is done for this to work with 3.0.  -Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else upgrading runs into the same problem I did, here's what I was doing in 2.8, and what I had to change in 3.0.

Comment: This is a library project that allows consumers of the library to inject overridden replacements for various interfaces.  The way open generic's worked in 2.8, the injected overrides for those where found first, and applied.  In 3.0, since the open generic are treated more standard, that no longer worked.  So - in the base setup of the container, i register all open generics last **after** any user overrides have been applied, using RegisterConditional